# How can I place img and text in a div box like this?

Tags: html, css

I have a div box that looks like this:

```
.productholder
{
width: 954px;
margin-left: 175px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
background-color: white; 
border-style:solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #d2d2d2;

/* gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
color-stop(0%, white), color-stop(50%, white), color-stop(170%, #f6f6f6)); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 55%, #f6f6f6 150%); 
}
```

And I am trying to get a structure of text and img like this example picture:

[image: Divbox]

But I cant seem get it exacly like the picture, any kind of help would be appreciate on how I can get my box to look like this example picture.

I have tried this so far:

```
<div class="productholder">  
  <img src="url" alt="" />
  <h2>Titletext</h2> 
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer mi. Vivamu. etc</p>       
  <input type="submit" value="More">
  <p>$599</p>
  <input type="submit" value="Buy">                                    
</div>

img{
float:left;
}

h2{
float:left;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: can you also include your CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an idea - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aWQ6q/)

***HTML***

```
<div class="productholder">  
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="" />

    <div class="productinfo">
        <h2>Titletext</h2> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer mi. Vivamu. etc</p>       
        <input type="submit" value="More">
    </div>

    <div class="productprice">
        <h2>$599</h2>
        <input type="submit" value="Buy">
    </div>        
</div>​
```

***CSS***

```css
.productholder {
    width: 954px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: white; 
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d2d2d2;

    /* gradients */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
    color-stop(0%, white), color-stop(50%, white), color-stop(170%, #f6f6f6)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 55%, #f6f6f6 150%); 
}

.productholder img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}

.productinfo {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 500px;
}

.productinfo input {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.productprice {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

for the image, h2 and first p do this

```
.productholder{
width: 734px;
padding-left: 220px;
}
.productholder img{
float:left;
margin: 10px;
max-width: 200px;
}
```

Then give the second p a class name and float right with `margin-right:10px;`
And for the inputs:

```
input{
position: absolute;
bottom: 5px;
right: 10px;
}
```

it's a rough sketch but it should be about right..

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple codeing:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="box-one">dfgdfg</div>
    <div class="box-two">dfgdfgdfgdfg</div>
    <div class="box-three">dfgdfgdfgdfg</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}

.wrapper{
    width:450px;
    background:#A4A4A4;
}

.box-one{
    float:left;
    width:80px;
}

.box-two{
    float:left;
    width:300x;
}

.box-three{
    float:right;
    width:70px;
}
```

I put the skeleton hear. Customize the css and use it. Cheer.....